# which package for full factorial experiment (5 parameters, 3 levels)?

Tags: r, experiment-design

I'm looking for a (convienent) package for `r` to construct an experiment design for five parameters and three levels (full factorial).
I'm only used to `FrF2` but it provides only two levels.

Sure, as soon as I post a question I find an answer:

```
gen.factorial {AlgDesign}
```

I will leave the question open, I'm curious for other information but I'm also fine when it gets closed.

Comment: Look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html

Comment: Thank you, I think I found it already :) Great that you're responding: Do you know if I can use this package (or another one) to create a split plot design, block one parameter with three levels for all parameters?

Comment: Look at the task view, they mention  that `skpr` can make split-plot designs, but certainly other packages there can help!